# Native query performance in Hibernate

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa

It's obvious that hql query is slower that native. There are project on the mind which will use huge amount of small transactions to perform. So question is what will perform better:

- native query in jpa
- native query through jdbc

How much difference is? Because of jpa mapping capabilities and prepared statements prefer it. But according to performance requirements it could be that hibernate will not be fast enough...

**EDIT**

1. replaced "Huge amount of data to process" to "huge amount of small transactions to perform"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a *way* too little info you have given.

#### Huge amount of data to process

- How huge is that? Like a few 10 millions of records of few 100 Gigabytes?
- How do you plan to process that data? If you pull it to the Java side via Hibernate (or native query or jdbc) then probably you are on a wrong track. You shall keep the data in the database, and process it there with the tools what the database offers for that, and lightyears more performant than any client-side processing. Consider database side processing (PL/SQL of Oracle, Transact SQL of MS SQL Server).
- What are you planning to optimize? Data insertion? Data retrieval? Are you planning to use select statements which dig trough a lots of data? Then consider an OLAP solution over classic OLTP. OLAP solutions are *built* for business intelligence and analyzing of huge gigabytes of data by a few clever tricks. Google for it (OLAP, Decision cubes)
- Can you use any of the capabilities of the underlying SQL engine? For example, if you are using Oracle, you have 1000 times more features available what you can actually use in Hibernate. For example, you just simply can not make an Oracle Text query in Hibernate, and there are really a lots of things you can not do.

I could sum this up that the performance difference is not between using native SQL or HQL. Instead:

- Hibernate is powerful in what it was built for: handing very few records of data, optimisitically caching it locally in the Java side as a groundwork for data processing systems built for databases which are not capable for data processing. (but only for some selects, inserts, updates, deletes)
- Once you really have to move huge amount of data, Java side processing is not an option. Programmers in the '80s have invented the stored procedures exactly because of this reason. Pick a database which supports database side processing to shortcut all network roundtrips, and imperative data processing with for-loops in your java code. Prefer instead as much declarative SQL as you can, and run the processing on your database.
- Once you are about to start using the features of your database, Hibernate will be pretty much in your way. It is really built as an ORM wrapper - however data processing problems are not CRUD and ORM-able problems all the time. For example, Hibernate is not too useful for an OLAP use case.

#### Huge amount of small transactions

In the case of having lots of small transactions (inserting/updating data to the database), Hibernate does not have any performance advantage (since no Java side caching can be utilized) disregarding of the database in use. However you may prefer hibernate since it is a nice tool for converting Java objects to SQL statements.

But with Hibernate, you are totally not in control on what is happening. For example, Hibernate + Oracle, inserting new entities to the database: this is the worst performance nightmare you can imagine.

This is what Hibernate does:

- select one new id from a sequence
- execute one insert
- repeat zillion of times

This is very much not performing well. (The sequence reference shall be part of the insert statement, the whole insert statement shall use JDBC batching.)

I found that a JDBC based approach runs about 1000 times quicker than the Hibernate in this particular use case. (Prefetching next 100 sequences, use JDBC Batch mode for Oracle, bind variables to the batch, send down records in batches of 100, and use asynchronous commit (yet again something you can not control in Hibernate).

I found that if I want to squeeze out most of your tools, I need to learn them in depth. Unfortunately you can find lots of opinion-based comments especially in Hibernate vs. non-Hibernate wars on the net. Most of them are written by Java developers who have literally no idea about what happens behind the scenes. So, don't believe - measure :)

Comment: I'm not database expert, and I was looking for some hints about where to look at and what I should looking for. Thanks. But one more thing. If ill switch some words in question and tell that i need to perform huge quantity of small transactions. What will be better in that case? Question updated.

Comment: Look for JDBC batch mode first, then check if your db allows async commits (http://www.orafaq.com/node/93). Watch out to actually commit after say every 100 or 1000 records, otherwise you will fill up the rollback segment (which will look like a database slowdown from your point of view).